# How to format rows to color group by like values in column 1

Tags: excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet that has information like this:

```
a
a
b
c
c
c
```

How do I format it so that all of the rows that have a value of `a` in the first column are one color, then all the rows that have a value of `b` in the first column are a different color, etc. ?

*Edit not from OP to add clarification from comment:*

Everything is already sorted alphabetically, and will stay that way, and I want multiple colors.

Comment: By using conditional formatting. Try to read the docs, it's well explained.

Comment: I am a novice at Excell. I guess I am trying to find something that will do it automatically? I can go and select the rows I want and just fill in a random color but I am trying to cut out time, and it seems that conditional formatting for each value will take substantially more time.

Comment: But it'd take even more time by doing it manually, and in any case, you have to define what colour will be assigned to what value, right?

Comment: it doesn't matter to me what color they are. I am just trying to visually separate the groups so that I can enter that data into another program more easily. I have about 10 different worksheets. One worksheet for each state and then a list of companies in each state

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternating coloring groups of rows in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020/alternating-coloring-groups-of-rows-in-excel) **(look at the highest voted answer which does not use VBA)**

Answer (score 10):

Create a helper column with a formula like this;

=MOD(IF(A3=A2,0,1)+B2,2)

In this example column A is the column of sorted values to be grouped by, and column B is the helper column.  The formula is entered on row 3.  Set the first row of the helper column to the value 0 and the others to the formula.  This will result in alternating values in the helper column for each group, ie;

```
a 0
a 0
b 1
c 0
c 0
c 0
d 1
d 1
e 0
```

You can then set conditional formatting based on the column value.  If the value is 1 then highlight the row; if it is 0 do not highlight it.  Or use alternating colors or whatever.  You can reference any of the articles on the web that describe how to conditional format the entire row based on the value in the column.

IF(A3=A2,0,1) compares the current row (3) and prior row (2) returning a 1 or 0.

MOD( [...] +B2,2) accomplishes the alternation between 0 and 1 when the grouping column value changes.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need a helper column, say B seeded with 1 in row1, and =IF(A1=A2,B1,B1+1) in B2 and copied down to suit. Then formulae of the kind below should suit for conditional formatting:

[image: SO18519394 example]

Comment: helper column is not necessary here and from context we can't be sure the values will always be sorted. Plus it sounds like they want multiple colors to tell teh groups apart at a glance

Comment: to avoid the helper column one would need to use a unique color (and rule) for each value. I now notice this was suggested in the comments and Kari (I did realize my mistake with pronoun and tried to "ninja-edit" but was too slow). didn't seem to like that approach. If the values will be kept sorted (admittedly not very difficult to do) then this should work splendidly (and then helper column can be hidden). Due to this I must admit my downvote was very premature and if you were to add to your answer somehow, I would be able to change my vote (it's locked down until an edit) as I like it now.

Comment: yes, everything is already sorted alphabetically, and will stay that way, and yes I want multiple colors

Comment: +1 I had a similar need and while your answer isn't perfect it did give me the idea to use `ISODD()` to highlight grouped rows.  Thanks!