# Formatting rows according to grouping column after filtering based on another column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet as follows.

```
A B
a 3
a 3
a 3
b 2
b 2
c 1
d 2
d 2
e 1
f 3
f 3
f 3
g 2
g 2
h 1
i 3
i 3
i 3
```

I would like to give alternate colours to rows according to groups in column A after filtering based on B. How to do this in excel?

I know without filtering this can be done ([How to format rows to color group by like values in column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519394/how-to-format-rows-to-color-group-by-like-values-in-column-1)).

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Do you want alternating colors of first and third *a* then the second *f* then the first and third *i* due to their association with *3* in the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select `A2:B19`
- Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- Enter the following formula:

`=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(1*($A$1:$A1<>$A$2:$A2),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$2:$B2,ROW($B$2:$B2)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B2)),0,1))),2) = 1`

- Choose formatting

Sample output with `2` filter:

[image]

First part of `SUMPRODUCT` counts number of group changes. `SUBTOTAL` as the second parameter excludes invisible rows.

Note: the above formula is pretty complex and volatile, it may affect performance of big datasets.

Comment: this solution fails if there are filtered rows within the same group, unless the data is sorted by Column `B` -- http://i.imgur.com/xc1ij3t.png

Answer (score 1):

Working with just an association with **3** in column B, I came up with the following.

[image: Alternating rows filtered highlights]

The CF rule for A1:B18 was created based upon the following formula.

```
=AND($B1=3, MOD(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1, 3), 2))
```

Additional CF rules with modified formulas would have to be created for rows that had **1** or **2** in column B.

Comment: this solution doesn't highlight grouped values in Column `A`.