# Libreoffice zebra pattern

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet on LibreOffice with songs name separated by Artist Name and Song Name.

But I want to sort them by Artist and make a pattern that groups the artists together.

This is the result I want:
[image]

As you can see I want a formula, probably on the C columns that will output False or True if the artist is different from it surrounding artist.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
=IF(A2=A1;D1;MOD(D1+1;2))
```

Source: [Alternating coloring groups of rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020/alternating-coloring-groups-of-rows-in-excel)